# printing a variable thats in a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I'm newer to python i have an understanding of most of it but i'm trying to understand classes and i can't get my code to work. Its not much at all but its just to help me understand it

```
class Phone(object):
    def __init__(self, words):
        self.words = words
    def phones(self):
        ph = ['Samsung', 'Apple', 'google', 'moto', 'LG']
a = Phone.phones(ph)
print a
```

I'm following Zed A. shaw's book [lpthw](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html)

The error code is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex40.py", line 34, in <module>
    a = Phone.phones(ph)
NameError: name 'ph' is not defined
```

Comment: What is not working? What do you aim to do?

Comment: What variable are you trying to print? Do you expect to see `['Samsung', 'Apple', 'google', 'moto', 'LG']` ?

Comment: im trying to print the list ph that's in the function phones that is in the class phone

Comment: i get an error code  im editing the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this bit is wrong `a = Phone.phones(ph)` you have to initialize the class first

```
a = Phone(['foo', 'bar'])
```

then you can go

```
print a.phones()
```

but that wont work either! the function `phones` doesn't return anything
possibly you want it to `return ph`

im guessing you probably want to build something like this:

```
class Phone(object):
    def __init__(self, words):
        self.words = words
    def phones(self):
        return self.words

a = Phone(['Samsung', 'Apple', 'google', 'moto', 'LG'])
print a.phones()
```

Comment: I want it to print the list as if it wasnt even in the class like this, say there is nothing in the file and i do ph = ['1', '2', '3'] then print ph

Answer (score 3):

At the moment printing `ph` from outside the class is impossible because it is a local variable and gets destroyed when the function finishes.

To make it accessible to the outer world you need to either declare it as `self.ph` or return it from the function:

### self.ph:

```
class Phone(object):
    def __init__(self, words):
        self.words = words
        self.ph = ['Samsung', 'Apple', 'google', 'moto', 'LG']

a = Phone("word1, word2")

print a.ph # ['Samsung', 'Apple', 'google', 'moto', 'LG']
```

### return:

```
class Phone(object):
        def __init__(self, words):
            self.words = words
        def phones(self):
            ph = ['Samsung', 'Apple', 'google', 'moto', 'LG']
            return ph

a = Phone("word1, word2").phones()

print a # ['Samsung', 'Apple', 'google', 'moto', 'LG']
```

Comment: Thanks i was trying to do the return one. I don't understand why it works though i'll explain why i think it works. It works because you print a and a is equal to the class phone and then 2 arguments then it runs the function phone. I guess im confused on the arguments now  on this line`a = Phone("word1, word2").phones()`

Comment: @jmonster555games Your close, basically `a = Phone("word1, word2").phone()` creates a new phone class with "word1, word2" as the `words` (I picked that string randomly but you could put what ever you want in there) then it calls the `phone()` method of the just created class which returns the array which gets stored into `a` by the equals sign. Then `print a` prints the array.

Comment: i'm still confused on why you need the arguments(words) i don't know why its there is what im trying to say. if you click the link on the post lpthw it will take you to the site im using to learn python. i didnt know why he had lyrics after self so i put my own thing in but don't know the purpose of it.